# Avoiding a large number of custom EventArgs?

Tags: c#, .net, events

The class library I'm refactoring has a large number of events (over 50) each with its own Delegate, even though many have the same arguments. I starting switching them all over to use EventHandler and custom EventArgs but it is proving to be tedious and time consuming.

Is there an easier way to handle a situation like this, when you have a huge number of events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You certainly don't need your own delegate type - you can use [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) where `TEventArgs` is your specific `EventArgs` subclass.

Refactoring a large mess is always time consuming and annoying. If you change to using method group conversions it can make it easier in the future though:

```
// This...
foo.SomeEvent += new MyCustomEventHandler(SomeMethod);

// becomes this..
foo.SomeEvent += SomeMethod;
```

Then if the type of `SomeEvent` changes, you can change `SomeMethod` and the subscription will just work, without having to be changed again.

Whether you need several different `EventArgs` subtypes is a different matter - and impossible to say without knowing about your particular situation. If you need to pass a wide variety of pieces of information, it may indeed make sense.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I just have to take a hard look at all these delegates.

Answer (score 2):

I use a templatized event args class like below to avoid having to create a large number of custom event args classes.

```
public class MessageEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public MessageEventArgs(T message)
    {
        Message = message;
    }

    public T Message
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was considering that, but it feels like it loses the desired *meaning* of the event arg - because the value is just "message" rather than "UserID", "ErrorCode" or whatever. (It does potentially achieve the goal stated in the question, of course - I'm just not sure whether it's a *good* way of achieving it.) You'd need one generic type for each arity - i.e. `MessageEventArgs<T>`, `MessageEventArgs<T1, T2>` etc... unless you use `MessageEventArgs<Tuple<string,string>>` on .NET 4. At that point the `EventHandler<T>` becomes horrific ;)